# How to make a selection of posts from the database with the condition?

Tags: mysql

How to choose the posts from the database with the condition. Already 2 days of head scratching do not understand how to win the query) I have 3 tables:
[image: Tables]

I need to choose the posts as shown on the picture:
[image: Select]

I get to make a selection of all positions whose pivot based table has a status of checked without conditions. But you must choose the post as shown in the picture, for example a post with id 39 if his column cheked status is checked in all rows. This means that all users have approved the post and it should show. Please tell me how to do such a condition in the query?

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT p.*
FROM posts p
WHERE NOT EXISTS(  SELECT 'a'
                   FROM post_user pu
                   WHERE pu.post_id = p.id
                   AND pu.checked = 'notChecked'
                 )
```